# Not typical NullPointer exception

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

Ok, first of all, I know what is `NullPointer` but wanted to ask what could cause such a behaviour.
I received crash on `Crittercism` and `stacktrace` is pointing to `List.add`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.xxx.android.activities.SuperActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:59)
at com.xxx.android.activities.XXXActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)
```

But the fact is that there is no list in `onCreate` or even the whole `SuperActivity`. 
What could cause such a `stacktrace` in `Android`? How can I find this `NullPointer` or similar source?

**EDIT**
As per request SuperActivity code around line 59:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (activitiesCreated == 0) {
        isFirstStart = true;
    }
    activitiesCreated++;
```

**EDIT 2**
I know how to follow stacktrace. What I want to know is what could be the problem and what can I do in cases like this?

**EDIT 3**
Stacktrace for the crashing thread:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.android/com.xxx.android.activities.XXXActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference    
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.xxx.android.activities.SuperActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:59)
at com.xxx.android.activities.XXXActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
... 9 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.xxx.android.activities.SuperActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:59) 
at com.xxx.android.activities.XXXActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)   
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)   
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What about in XXXActivity? Gotta just trace these errors back as far as they go

Comment: What is the line #59?

Comment: @JoeFrostick There is no smell of List anywhere near stacktrace anywhere.

Comment: can you post that region of code?

Comment: @DanielZolnai integer incrementing

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: This is a surprising error and I also wouldn't know how to analyse it. Is there a chance you can reproduce this problem or figure out under what conditions/environment it happens? Maybe this gives more insight or an idea to follow.

Comment: (I've never used Crittercism) but is this crash report referring to the same build as the source you are looking at? Has the build that crashed been made with proguard? Could lead to inconsistencies between the source and the apk.

Comment: Is there any chance you are looking at source from the wrong version of the library?

Comment: @DanielS. No, I cannot reproduce it. But it is the first activity on Application startup.

Comment: @ColinGillespie Tim B - yes, I checked all versions, not just the one that is shown in Crittercism

Comment: Could it possible you extend the _wrong_ `SuperActivity` class by having some wrong import statement in your xxxActivity?

Comment: @TmKVU No, I checked everything. I tried checking every possibility before posting here.

Comment: I will bet for the proguard theory are you using it?

Comment: @Nanoc Yes, I am using Proguard. But even if it messes up line numbers, there still is not a single reference to List in onCreate(). And our proguard configuration keeps activities

Comment: Could you use a breakpoint and go step by step to where it crash?

Comment: Just an idea: Put in code List list = null; list.add("abc"); and see if it has the same exception message "Attempt to invoke interface method ...". If not, maybe there is some stuff with reflection going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Nanoc: he can't reproduce the problem, so debugging is not an option.

Comment: so it has crashed at least once and has got the stack trace but it doesnt crash anymore?? its a device-related issue then?

Comment: @Nanoc it is live version, so I do not know how it got crashed. I did not ask question to get solution for this exact issue. I just really got interested in what could cause such a behaviour...

Comment: You must get wrong on XXXActivity ' onCreared(). plz provide code.

Comment: XXXActivity extends SuperActivity